# Need help with an integral related to beta function

Tags: calculus, integration, beta-function

I've been struggling with a definite integral as below:

$$
\int_0^1 x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b}(I_x(a+1,b) - 1) dx
$$

where $I_{x}$ represents the regularized incomplete beta function.

I'd initially tackled it as an integration by parts problem with

$$dv=x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b}$$
$$u=I_x(a+1,b) - 1$$

however couldn't get a sensible answer at all. I'd really appreciate any help people could offer, or even an opinion on whether an analytical answer is a hopeless case!

Comment: What exactly does $I_{x}$ stand for?

Comment: @kolobokish It's the regularized incomplete beta function $$I_x(a,b) = B_x(a,b) /  B(a,b)$$

Comment: Maybe you can differentiate under the integral sign and then integrate it once more? This could be helpful regarding the incompleteness part, as it is a function of upper limit (or of upper case, I don't know the exact name.)