# Integral involving incomplete beta function

Tags: integration, statistics, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function, beta-function

I have the following integral,

$$\int_{0}^1x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}B_x(c,d)dx$$

where $B_x(c,d) = \int_{0}^xt^{c-1}(1-t)^{d-1}dt$ is the [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function), and $a,b,c,d>0$.

**Question**: Does this have a closed form?

---

**My attempt**:

- First, playing around in Wolfram Alpha makes me think that there may be a (simple?) closed form: [example 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(x%5E3%20(1-x)%5E2%20Beta(x,1,8))%20dx) and [example 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(x%5E2%20(1-x)%5E1%20Beta(x,12,2))%20dx). The second example can also be written as $\int x^2(1-x)B_x(12,2)dx = \frac{1}{4}(B_x(16,2) - x^4B_x(12,2))+\frac{1}{3}(x^3B_x(12,2)-B_x(15,2))$.
- It seems there is a reduction when $a=c$, $b=d$ as
  $$\int_0^1 x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}B_x(a,b)dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}\right)^2$$
  where $\Gamma(a)$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). However, for the case when $a\neq c$, $b\neq d$, things are not quite as clear for me.
- I found a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020371/need-help-with-an-integral-related-to-beta-function) but it has not been answered.
- I also found [this](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/21/01/02/02/) but I'm not sure if it is useful.

Comment: do you have any reason to expect that it does? Also: what have you tried?

Comment: @clathratus I've updated my post to address your questions

Comment: Thank you for your update. I have retracted my close vote and up-voted your question.

Comment: First note that $B_x(c,\,d)=\int_0^1x^cz^{c-1}(1-zx)^{d-1}dz$ so your integral is $$\int_{[0,\,1]^2}x^{a+c-1}(1-x)^{b-1}(1-zx)^{d-1}dxdz.$$It's mentioned in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type that $$\Re c>\Re b>0\implies\int_0^1x^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-b-1}(1-zx)^{-a}dx=\operatorname{B}(b,\,c-b)\,{}_2F_1(a,\,b;\,c;\,z).$$Unfortunately the notation is a little different from your problem's, but at least you can now write the result as an $\int_0^1dz$ integral of a hypergeometric function.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks! Do you know of any simplification of $\int_0^1 {}_2F_1(a,b;c;z)dz$ when $a,b,c$ are positive integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [hypergeometric representation](http://functions.wolfram.com/06.19.26.0005.01)  of the incomplete Beta function
\begin{equation}
B_x\left( c,d \right)=\frac{x^c}{c}{}_2F_1\left( c,1-d;1+c;x \right)
\end{equation} 
the integral can be written as
\begin{align}
I\left( a,b,c,d \right)&=\int_{0}^1x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}B_x(c,d)\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{c}\int_{0}^1x^{a+c-1}(1-x)^{b-1}{}_2F_1\left( c,1-d;1+c;x \right)\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{c}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(c)_k(1-d)_k}{(1+c)_kk!} \int_0^1x^{a+c+k-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{c}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(c)_k(1-d)_k}{(1+c)_kk!} \frac{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(a+c+k)}{\Gamma(a+b+c+k)}\\
&=\frac{1}{c}\frac{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(a+c)}{\Gamma(a+b+c)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(c)_k(1-d)_k}{(1+c)_kk!} \frac{(a+c)_k}{(a+b+c)_k}\\
&=\frac{1}{c}\frac{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(a+c)}{\Gamma(a+b+c)}\,{}_3F_2\left( 1-d,a+c,c;1+c,a+b+c ;1\right)
\end{align} 
Using [this identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.27.17.0034.01) for the generalized hypergeometric function:
\begin{equation}
 {}_3F_2\left( a_1,a_2,a_3;b_1,b_2;1 \right)=\frac{\Gamma(b_1)\Gamma(b_1+b_2-a_1-a_2-a_3)}{\Gamma(b_1-a_1)\Gamma(b_1+b_2-a_2-a_3)}{}_3F_2\left( a_1,b_2-a_2,b_2-a_3;b_2,b_1+b_2-a_2-a_3;1 \right)
\end{equation} 
Here we choose $a_1=1-d,a_2=a+c,a_3=c,b_1=a+b+c,b_2=1+c$ to obtain
\begin{align}
I\left( a,b,c,d \right)&=\frac{1}{c}\frac{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(a+c)}{\Gamma(a+b+c)}\frac{\Gamma(a+b+c)\Gamma(b+d)}{\Gamma(a+b+c+d-1)\Gamma(b+1)}\,{}_3F_2\left( 1-d,1-a,1;1+c,1+b ;1\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{bc}\frac{\Gamma(a+c)\Gamma(b+d)}{\Gamma(a+b+c+d-1)}\,{}_3F_2\left( 1,1-a,1-d;1+b,1+c ;1\right)\\
&=\frac{a+b+c+d-1}{bc}B(a+c,b+d)\,{}_3F_2\left( 1,1-a,1-d;1+b,1+c ;1\right)
\end{align} 
which gives simple results if $a$ or $d$ are positive integer, as the hypergeometric series is finite: as $1-a\le0$ or $1-b\le0$, in the [series definition](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.27.06.0001.01) of the hypergeometric function, there are $\operatorname{min}(a,b)$ terms (numerator of the coefficients cancel after that).  One can also check the given result when $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Comment: Thank you! I have a few questions: 1) is $z$ in the RHS of the first equation suppose to be $x$? 2) I think the identity was applied incorrectly, the second to last line I obtain is $I(a,b,c,d) = \frac{1}{bc}\frac{\Gamma(a+c)\Gamma(b+d)}{\Gamma(c+d)} {}_{3}F_2(1-d,b,a+b;a+b+c,b+1;1)$. 3) I can assume all numbers are integers greater than 0 (I should have included this in the problem statement); how does the hypergeometric series simplify (can you point me to a reference)?

Comment: You're welcome. 1) sorry, typo corrected. 2) and 3) Details are added in the answer. A typo is also corrected in the last expression.